# Browser cache or Local storage?

Tags: reactjs, browser, local-storage, browser-cache

I have a huge list of products like 800-1000 may be more[dynamic].In the admin panel I want to show the list. Each time fetching the data takes time and admin has to wait. So if  I want to save the data on first fetch and store it locally to reuse faster.

**Which one would be better local storage or  browser cache ?**

Comment: It's better you use lazy loading. Fetching and storing huge data, adds to additional memory usage and might slowdown your app.

Comment: How would code “use browser cache” here?